# How to fix closure in react when using addEventListener and useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've made a simple example of a counter and want to console log value on mouse click, but it always displays 0. How can fix it?

```
import "./App.css";
import { useState } from "react";
import { useEffect } from "react";

function App() {
  const [num, setNum] = useState(0);

  const handler = () => {
    console.log(num);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("click", handler);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <div
          onClick={() => {
            setNum(num + 1);
          }}
        >
          Add
        </div>
        <h1>{num}</h1>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that whenever your component re-renders itself (due to state change), a new value is set for `num`, **and** a new function is created for `handler`.

However, your event handler inside the `useEffect` will never see the new function created for `handler`, therefore it will keep calling the old function, which still holds a reference to the old value of `num`, which is zero.

Here is a quick fix to get your code to kinda start working:

```
import "./App.css";
import { useEffect, useState, useCallback } from "react";


function App() {
  const [num, setNum] = useState(0);

  const handler = useCallback(() => {
    console.log(num);
  }, [num]);

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("click", handler);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("click", handler);
    };
  }, [handler]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <div
          onClick={() => {
            setNum(num + 1);
          }}
        >
          Add
        </div>
        <h1>{num}</h1>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

When you run this, you will see that the value printed in the console is lagging behind the value printed in the console. I'll leave it to you to figure out why.

If you really want to use an event listener, rather than doing what the other answers have suggested, you can try something like this:

```
import "./App.css";
import { useEffect, useState, useRef, useCallback } from "react";


function App() {
  const [num, setNum] = useState(0);
  const numRef = useRef(num);

  const handler = useCallback(() => {
    console.log(numRef.current);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("click", handler);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("click", handler);
    };
  }, [handler]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <div
          onClick={() => {
            setNum(num => {
              numRef.current = num + 1;
              return numRef.current;
            })
          }}
        >
          Add
        </div>
        <h1>{num}</h1>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This last one works for two reasons:

1. The `handler` is using a reference to the latest version of `num`, and this reference will always stay up-to-date because we update it in the `setNum` callback. This also means that `handler` will not change between renders.
2. The event handler will not have to be removed each time `num` changes, which was causing the console.log to lag behind the value of num.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the `useEffect` to check for changes in the `num` state rather than adding an unnecessary `addEventListener`.

```js
const { useEffect, useState } = React;

function Example() {

  const [ num, setNum ] = useState(0);

  function handler() {
    setNum(num + 1);
  }

  useEffect(() => console.log(num), [num]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <div onClick={handler}>Add</div>
        <h1>{num}</h1>
      </header>
    </div>
  );

}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: You are right, but the problem is all about addEventListener, that num is not changing inside handler

Comment: OK @Dimchykus why do you think `addEventListener` is necessary? Why is it your code? What are you hoping to achieve with it?